# C# Redirect Standard Output

Tags: c#

I have a console program that displays progress constantly in one line, I haven't been able to find anything on the internet that works...
I'm using a WinForm and want to display progress in a progress bar.

Example:

```
processing:  0.02% [  2.40 MB/sec]
```

(note that the extra spaces are replaced with actual numbers depending on speed and percentage)

At the end it will say

```
processing: finish  [  2.75 MB/sec]
error - failed on B_CAS_CARD::get_pwr_on_ctrl() : code=-6
```

Don't mind the error, it's because I have no card inserted.

So my question is how can I redirect that output while it's *streaming*?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want done. Redirect where? Why?

Comment: I want the output to be redirected to a Windows Form - progress bar, I think I mentioned that?

Comment: Also are you running a separate console program from you GUI application? Or can you just link the program/functions into your main application and avoid going via the command line (and having to parse/redirect output)

Comment: So you want your WinForms program to run a console application, capture its standard output, and display that text in your program's control?

Comment: the console program is made in C++, not from me, and it's unable to be converted to C# because of MULTI2 broadcast decryption...

yes, but I have tried using process.StandardOutput.ReadLine and .ReadToEnd, but neither work or report any process at all, only when it's finished...

Comment: If you have access to the source code of the console program you could still "link" it into the GUI application via PInvoke or C++/CLI (not sure if that would be a better solution, but it is a potential option)

Comment: Yes I do have access to the source, I built it myself actually, because of some reasons... But I have no idea how that works.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you want here. Do you have a winforms application that starts a console application and you want to capture the output of the console application and show it in the winforms application? Or do you have 1 application that both uses a console and winforms?

Comment: I have a WinFrom and a console, but I can't manage to capture output while it's running (if it helps, the C++ part for the processing display is this: fprintf(stderr, "\rprocessing: %2d.%02d%% [%6.2f MB/sec]", m/100, m%100, mbps);)

Comment: The normal way is that the winforms application starts the dos program in the console after setting it up and redirecting its output.

Comment: @Taw thats not working at every case. Redirected output would be catched only in case the console programm performed buffer flush. otherwise you will take output only after 'final flush' at programm end.